# Getting value from response body using Request module

Tags: node.js, request, http-post, response

I am using request module to post data to an oracle db. I set the headers like so

```
headers: {
 'Accept': 'application/json',
 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
},
```

The response body I get is this however

```
 { Output:     { X_RETURN_STATUS: 'S',      X_MSG_DATA: null } }
```

This is not JSON.

I want to be able to get the value 'S' out of it and put it into a variable so I can pass it through another post Request.

The main question is how to get the value 'S' by using the keys Output and `X_RETURN_STATUS`? 
Is there a relatively easy way to get to it without it being in JSON form.

Comment: Some actual code would have been nice, rather than just snippets without context. But I assume `request` simply parsed the JSON response into a JS object.
Did you try accessing it with `body.Output.X_RETURN_STATUS`?

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks Lucas S.!